# Internal server error,godaddy problem?

Tags: linux, mysql, hosting

I added subdomain,create a new folder,than put some files in folder,when I try to access my new subdomain I get this message `500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.`
Can someone help me with this please?It is linux hosting with mysql database.

Comment: A bit more details on the subdomain and folder, and how you access this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access a html only file on the site? Upload a file with just some simple text in it. Can you load it? If not, look for the .htaccess file and rename it to something else. Now try to load the text file. If you can load it then its a issue with htaccess if not, time to look at the server logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 as it states, is a server side error.

By that I mean that it's not GoDaddy that's causing the problem but most likely some configuration on your server, in your case I would guess that Wordpress and/or Apache are not configured properly.

One thing you might want to check is your Apache configuration it should include a VirtualHost for the subdomain.

Like this:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/httpd/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/httpd/htdocs/subdomain/
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: This configuration would be done in the hhtpd.conf file (usually at /etc/Apache2/ )